# Add to existing spreadsheet?

Tags: python, csv

I have a spreadsheet with fieldnames:

['name', 'occupation', 'company', 'address', 'address_2','city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone,' 'fax', 'email', 'website', 'description']

and would like to add to this spreadsheet other spreadsheets of data that contain fewer fieldnames (although all of the others' fieldnames are included in this spreadsheet).

I'm getting a bizarre error:

```
Samuel-Finegolds-MacBook-Pro:~ samuelfinegold$ /var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/merge-395698810.980.py.command ; exit;
['name', 'occupation', 'company', 'address', 'address_2', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone,fax', 'email', 'website', 'description']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/noodle/merge.py", line 14, in <module>
    gc_all_dict.writerow(row)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
    ", ".join(wrong_fields))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
logout

[Process completed]
```

When I run the following:

```
import csv

# compile master spreadsheet
with(open('gc_all.txt','w')) as gc_all:

    fieldnames = ['name', 'occupation', 'company', 'address', 'address_2','city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone,' 'fax', 'email', 'website', 'description']
    gc_all_dict = csv.DictWriter(gc_all, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter = '\t')
    print gc_all_dict.fieldnames

    with(open('/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/noodle/aicep/aicep_scrape_output.txt', 'rU')) as aicep:
        aicep_dict = csv.DictReader(aicep, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in aicep_dict:
#             print row
            gc_all_dict.writerow(row)


    for row in gc_all:
        print row
```

Fake data:

```
name    occupation  company address address_2   city    state   zip phone   fax email   website description
Rob Er      Step Up 123 Road Dr     New York    NY  10011   1234567891  1234567891  a@b.com www.stepUp.com  A great counselor
Bob B. Bob      For Your Rights 12 2nd Ave      San Francisco   CA  94109   1234567891  1234567891  c@d.com     
Snob Job        Marley Inc. 12 1st Ave      Denver  CO  80231   1234567891  1234567891  g@h.com     What a counselor!
```

Comment: Can you give us a small sample aicep_scrape_output.txt file so we can debug this?

Comment: Someone has probably already asked this, but is there some reason that you aren't using a higher-level library like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)?

Comment: @DSM: Good question in general… but if all he's doing is concatenating heterogeneous CSVs into a superset CSV to use in Excel or something, `pandas` won't add anything useful (except maybe a better error message when the doubly-unexpected happens…).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is that, despite what you claim in your question, all of the others' fieldnames are *not* included in this spreadsheet.

You can tell by looking at the line above the one that raised. [`DictWriter._dict_to_list`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/csv.py#l138) looks like this:

```
def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
    if self.extrasaction == "raise":
        wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
        if wrong_fields:
            raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: " +
                             ", ".join(wrong_fields))
    return [rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames]
```

So, it found a field that isn't in your `DictWriter`.

---

But why is it raising that weird error while trying to create the error? Because the missing field is named `None`. The `DictWriter` code isn't built to handle that. So, that's problem #2.

---

And why is the field named `None`? Because that's what a `DictReader` produces whenever it finds a column that doesn't fit into the `fieldnames` that you gave it.  You can see this by `print row`: One of the elements of the `dict` will be something like `None: 'foo'`. So, that's problem #3.

---

So how do you fix this?

Well, the obvious thing to do is make your claim true: Make the fields in your target a strict superset of the fields in your source.

Alternatively, you can tell your `DictReader` to skip extra fields, or your `DictWriter` to ignore them instead of raising. For example, just add `extrasaction='ignore'` to your `DictWriter` constructor, and the problem will go away.

But really, you shouldn't be doing that. `raise` caught a legitimate bug for you here; it just didn't do so with a very useful error message.

Comment: I'm impressed. Also, even if the code succeeds, the next line `for row in gc_all:` will surely fail.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good point. Also, given that he apparently wanted to concatenate a bunch of CSV files together, using `w` instead of `a` or `w+` is probably a bad idea…

Comment: "he" will change the mode to w+

Comment: Also, this is an incredibly well-written answer. Thank you. I've posted my share of ignorant questions on this site and received few answers that delve into the issue, explaining in clear, well though-out sentences how to understand and address the error. Cheers!

Comment: @goldisfine: You will also want to `seek` to the beginning (or close and then reopen in `'r'` mode) before trying to iterate over the file at the end; otherwise it'll just successfully print out nothing (since you're already at the end of the file). BTW, if the "he" in quotes is because you're actually a "she" (or a genderless AI or an alien whose sex can't be described in puny earth terms), apologies; your tiny thumbnail appears to be of a man, but not everyone's thumbnail is actually a picture of the user, so that was a silly assumption.

Comment: @goldisfine: Also, thanks for the edits. Silly grammar mistakes are just as easy to make as silly code mistakes (although I think I make even more of the latter on a daily basis…).

Comment: I'm a guy, but I'm not the guy in the pic (that's Andy Murray, and if you don't know who he is you need to spend less time on SO and more time watching tennis :)