# DictWriter not receiving my data from DictReader

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6

I'm reading a `csv` file with the first row being my header row.  I've verified that the headers are being passed in correctly, but my outfile remains blank.  It's not kicking up any errors.

```
def main():
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    myreader = csv.DictReader(open(infile, 'rbU'))
    for line in myreader:
        print(line['ADDR_NAME'])
    mywriter = csv.DictWriter(open(outfile, 'wb'), 
                              fieldnames=myreader.fieldnames)
    #print(mywriter.fieldnames)
    for row in myreader:
        mywriter.writerow(outfile)
```

Comment: You're not closing `outfile`. Also when dealing with files, it's preferable to use `with` statements, e.g. `with open(...) as f: ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a dict to `mywriter.writerow` in your last line, not a string (file path) as you're currently doing. See the [writer docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

If you're just trying to copy all of the lines from `myreader` to `mywriter`, you'll also want to rearrange things a bit: Open both your reader and your writer first, then merge your two `for` loops:

```
def main():
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    myreader = csv.DictReader(open(infile, 'rbU'))
    mywriter = csv.DictWriter(open(outfile, 'wb'),
                              fieldnames=myreader.fieldnames)
    for row in myreader:
        print(row['ADDR_NAME'])
        mywriter.writerow(row)
```

As Cristian mentions, it also is good practice to `.close` files you `open`, but that shouldn't be causing your problem here.

Comment: What confuses me is what to refer to the `DictReader` dictionary as.  So should I pass it `mywriter.writerow(row)`?

Comment: When you iterate over a `DictReader`, you get dicts, so yes, whatever variable name you use in your `for` loop (`row`, in this case) is a dict suitable for passing to `mywriter.writerow`.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the first `for` in OP's example exhausts `myreader`, so the second `for` has zero iterations.

Comment: `outfile` is a string, not a file object.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Good call. Edited.

Comment: `mywriter.writerow(outfile)` -> `mywriter.writerow(row)` if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yep, typed too quickly and missed the _main_ change I was trying to suggest. Thanks for straightening that out (and for the doc link fix)!

Comment: So now I have `myreader = csv.DictReader(open(infile, 'rbU'))
 mywriter = csv.DictWriter(open(outfile, 'wb'),
                              filenames=myreader.fieldnames)
 print(mywriter.fieldnames)
 for row in myreader:
  mywriter.writerow(row)` and I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @flybonzai That keyword-related error is a weird one, but I think autocorrect must have kicked in—I called the second `DictWriter` argument `filenames` when it should've been `fieldnames`. Try that.

Comment: @myersjustinc It must have been something like autocorrect.  Now I'm getting a different error: `Nabeel and Barbara Jabbour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pre_process2.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "./pre_process2.py", line 21, in main
    mywriter.writerow(row)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/csv.py", line 144, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/csv.py", line 140, in _dict_to_list
    ", ".join(wrong_fields))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
`

Comment: @flybonzai That usually suggests [your row included a fieldname that your DictWriter wasn't expecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686328/add-to-existing-spreadsheet), but that seems hard to believe since you're just copying things over. Consider adding `extrasaction='ignore'` when you create `mywriter` and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: @myersjustinc I have a bunch of fields that may or may not be defined, do you think that may be the problem?  It is looking for a defined value, but possible finding `''`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87203/discussion-between-myersjustinc-and-flybonzai).